# How can i add scroll bar in table tag in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html-table, horizontal-scrolling

I have a  in that dividing two  columns that each one have one line chart drawing but i want to set scroll bar for the two line chart individually they are in two  values. how can i set the scroll bar horizantally in table contains two td values.

Comment: Can you post your Asp code here?

Comment: Kindly check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TweNm/). If you found your answer here kindly up vote my comment. Thanks